# With Maven 3 is it possible to run JUNIT tests using a version of java different from what is set in the compile plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-3, junit4

My project must be built using JAVA 1.3 so I use the following compile plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.3</source>
        <target>1.3</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

. However, during the build I require JUNIT4 tests to be executed so I need the sunfire plugin to use java 1.6. Is this possible in maven 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your plugin configuration to something like this instead:

```xml
<plugin>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.3</source>
                <target>1.3</target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

check the surefire plugin and its attribute "jvm"

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html